# Coding a family tree style app

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to code up an app. ( for my own learning) that helps build a family tree. So I want the user to add the users grandparents, parents etc. to this app. and I want to be able to maintain this data. I am wondering what components would go into this. Here's what I am thinking:
- A database - that has all the info.
- front end ( iOS app) that pulls data from this database.

Questions:
- Is a database the right way to go ?
- Any recommendations on the database to use ?
- Any code samples/recommendations on the approach to take ?

I want to make sure the system is scalable and hopefully build a WEB fronted in addition to an app fronted.

Any thoughts from the more experienced coders on how you would approach this problem ?

Comment: This question is pretty broad but yes, a database is a good plan. Either use SQLite, FMDB (an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite), or go with Core-Data.

Comment: Check out the [Pedigree Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094). I agree with the database approach, but to pull the data, you may need to brush up on recursion techniques.

Comment: A hierarchy is typically achieved by giving each record a self_id and a parent_id. Then use recursion to traverse the branches. Google around, you'll find a solution.

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure out something? Could you please post here for the purpose of helping the others in future?

Comment: @cocoacoder did you figure out anything about family tree app, as I have also same requirement. Your help will be much appriciated to me and others.